# Automatic redirect to login page with IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication. I have added an AuthorizeAttribute to my HomeController. When authorization fails, I would like for it to redirect to the IdentityServer, specifically calling the SignIn action of my AccountController - don't see any other way to do this. My SignIn method looks like:

```
            var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            var url = Settings.AuthorizeEndpoint +
                "?client_id=" + Settings.ClientId +
                "&response_type=id_token" +
                "&scope=openid email public" +
                "&redirect_uri=" + Settings.RedirectUri +
                "&response_mode=form_post" +
                "&state=" + state +
                "&nonce=" + nonce;

            SetTempCookie(state, nonce);
            return Redirect(url);
```

Is there an easier way to do this, other than writing my own custom Authorization attribute?

Comment: Does settings represent the settings for the identity server?  I'm trying to implement sign in as well and not having a lot of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it manually - that's the way it works.

The Katana OpenID Connect middleware could simplify this - if you can use this library.

Comment: Can you post the link to this?  Thanks.